# Why do I get the message "source not found" from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to Eclipse. When I debug and enter some function, I get the message
"Source not found" despite the code is mine. How can I solve this issue? Is there an addon that might help?

I get error class not found exception with source not found but when I press for F6 (lot)I proceed with the debugging ,the issue is just when I press F5 and want to dive in to some method code (of mine btw that just on different package)– FedorE

Comment: Is the function part of standard library

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your source code in the debug configuration:

Perform the one of the steps below:

Option1:

```
 Right Click(Java Source) -> Debug As -> Java Applications
```

Option2: If option1 doesn't help:

```
 Menu ->Run ->Debug Configurations..-> Java Applications ->RightClick & select New.
 In right side, 
   Enter Name
   Browse your Project and the class having `main` method
   In Classpath, add your project from workspace
 Click Debug button in the bottom
```

Let me know, if it doesn't help.

Comment: i think he should add the java source code cause i didnt saw same error if source is mine.

Comment: it doesnt help since the files are not in the same package

Comment: I get error class not found exception with source not found but when I press for F6 (lot)I proceed with the debugging ,the issue is just when I press F5 and want to dive in to some method code

Comment: @FedorE: When it says `source Not found`, which class name your see in the screen? It must not be one of your classes, but it should be one from some framework tool. You need to add the source of that framework too. If you don't want to move inside that framework, then at that screen, press `F7`, and then do `F5` one. If it doesn't help, then share the line of code where you are pressing `F5`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because , while you are in debug, the debugger enters part of code which does not have attached source files.

what you can do is,

**IF you have got the source to that file :**

when you see that source not found screen,  there would be a `Attach Source` button. press that, and browse to file that should contain source for that class. and hit ok. eclipse will load the source and you would be good to go.

Sometimes debugger on repetitive `step into` enters some API classes or plugins whose source you may not have, then your best bet is to repetitively press `F6` till debugger exists that class